# How to uplad program into Arduino Nano Clone with CH340?

Tags: arduino, usb, avr, bootloader, atmega328p

I've started to build a Arduino Nano with **CH340g** using this schematic:

[image]

Which use the CH340 chip :

[image]

With one difference, I've use SPI pin to program the MCU.

I've uploaded [OptiBoot](https://github.com/Optiboot/) to Atmega328 and then I've set BLB1 to lock LPM and SPM in the boot section and I've set the BOOTRST fuse to One.

All the process below was also done in Win7 with installed driver from the original IC [website](http://www.wch.cn/download/CH341SER_EXE.html).

When the board connects to UBUNTU the computer recognize the device as : **QinHeng Electronics HL-340 USB-Serial adapter** and when I tried to upload the code, It uploads the code(famous blink) with Arduino IDE(set to use Arduino Nano) for a few times(If i get lucky) and the it stops.

The other strange thing is when I use Arduino bootloader to print something in serial, I can see it in terminal through USB but when
I upload the hex file of echo program:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include<avr/io.h>

#define USART_BAUDRATE 9600
#define BAUD_PRESCALE (((F_CPU/(USART_BAUDRATE*16UL)))-1)

int main(void){
 char recieved_byte;
 
 UCSR0B |= (1<<RXEN0)  | (1<<TXEN0);
 UCSR0C |= (1<<UCSZ00) | (1<<UCSZ01);
 UBRR0H  = (BAUD_PRESCALE >> 8);
 UBRR0L  = BAUD_PRESCALE;
 
    for(;;){
  // wait until a byte is ready to read
  while( ( UCSR0A & ( 1 << RXC0 ) ) == 0 ){}

  // grab the byte from the serial port
  recieved_byte = UDR0;
  
  // wait until the port is ready to be written to
  while( ( UCSR0A & ( 1 << UDRE0 ) ) == 0 ){}

  // write the byte to the serial port
  UDR0 = recieved_byte;
    }
    return 0;   /* never reached */
}
```

I couldn't communicate(It doesn't echo back)!

How can I fix this? any help would be appreciated.

**PS:**
My goal is not to build an Arduino and I want to communicate to my MCU through USB and I've thought it would be good start to build an Arduino to test super cheap CH340 on the already tested schematic!

**UPDATE1**:

There are [reported](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=695835.0) problem with ch340 in Arduino boards but non of those solutions helps! I guess if ch340g was that good, It would became  standard USB serial chip in all devices with its low price.

**UPDATE2**:

I've manage to make MCU echo back(without Arduino boot loader) correctly by tuning parameters(F_CPU and BAUD_PRESCALE) but self programming is seems far fetch!

Comment: _"when I upload the hex file of echo program:.. It doesn't echo back"_ - what happens if you disconnect TX and RX from the MCU and wire them together at the CH340 to loop back the signal? Are you using the specified **Green** LED on the TX line? Do you have an oscilloscope to see the TX waveform?

Comment: Looping back signals is a good idea let me test that, I've removed LEDs from Rx and TX line to eliminate any interference, they(rx/tx line) connected via a 1k resistor to MCU, but at first they exist and on the send/receive they light up. unfortunately I don't have an oscilloscope.

Comment: Wiring RX and TX works, I mean when I type ,it echo back, I guess the ch340 chip is fine.